# Как узнать номер вхождения символа из регулярного выражения для заданной строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, sed

Как-то так:

```
echo "абвгд" | sed 's/в/\1{фокус}/` # получим: aбв3гд
```

Т.е. буква "в" стоит третьей и этот то номер необходимо вычленить, это возможно?

Comment: а awk  можно добавить? ?

Answer (score 5):

Получилось как то так:

```
 echo "абвгд" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sed -n 'p;/в/=' | sed -n 'H;${x;s/\n//g;p}'
```

Первый `sed` разбивает строку на строки с отдельными символами. Второй - после строки с буквой "в" печатает ее номер. Третий - собирает символы обратно в строку.

При наличии perl, это конечно было бы проще:

```
 echo "абвгд" | perl -Ca -pe 's/в/$&.(length($`)-1)/e'
```

Comment: *За один вызов sed так сделать не получится, таких возможностей в нем просто нет.* — если подсчёт символов возложить ну другую программу, то возможность есть.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Весь интернет перерыл на запуск внешних программ из строки замены ... плохо искал ... а без запуска пришел к выводу, что невозможно

Comment: Люди ханойские башни на sed решают... б

Answer (score 5):

если делать одним вызовом интерпретатора *sed*, получается довольно многословно (но наверняка можно чуть-чуть сократить при острой необходимости).

для подсчёта количества символов используется программа *wc*:

```
$ echo "абвгд" | sed -r 's/в/&\n/;h;s/^/echo -n "/;s/\n.*/"|wc -m/e;G;s/^(.+)\n(.+)\n/\2\1/'
```

---

небольшое пояснение по коду программы для интерпретатора *sed*:

- `s/в/&\n/` — добавляем после искомого символа символ перевода строки `\n`. дальше мы будем использовать его как маркер
- `h` — сохраняем текущее содержимое *pattern space* (`абв\nгд`) в *hold space* (оно нам понадобится чуть позже)
- `s/^/echo -n "/` — вставляем в начало *pattern space* строку `echo -n "`
- `s/\n.*/"|wc -m/e`:

  - `s/\n.*/"|wc -m/` — заменяем всё, начиная с символа `\n` (мы его добавили на первом шаге) до конца *pattern space* на строку `"|wc -m`. теперь в *pattern space* у нас получилось: `echo -n "абв"|wc -m`. если эту строку выполнить в оболочке, то она вернёт символ `3` (количество символов в строке `абв`)
  - `e` — с помощью этого модификатора команды `s` мы как раз и передаём содержимое *pattern space* в оболочку, чтобы она выполнила это содержимое как команду. результат выполнения этой команды заменит текущее содержимое *pattern space* (и в *pattern space* у нас будет символ `3`)
- `G` — эта команда добавляет в конец *pattern space* символ перевода строки, а затем содержимое *hold space*. в результате в *patten space* у нас получилась строка `3\nабв\nгд`
- `s/^(.+)\n(.+)\n/\2\1/` — выбираем всё до первого символа `\n` (т.е., строку `3`) в первую группу, всё между первым и вторым символом `\n` (т.е., строку `абв`) — во вторую, а затем выводим группы в обратном порядке — сначала вторую, потом первую: `абв`, затем `3`. а остаток строки (`гд`) остаётся нетронутым
- в результате получаем в *pattern space* строку `абв3гд`, что и требовалось.

Answer (score 2):

С использованием промежуточного "огорода" в  виде `awk`:

```
echo "abcde" | awk 'match($0, /d/) {print substr($0, 0, RSTART),RSTART,substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH)}' | sed 's/ //g'
```

Comment: Вот только искомый символ пропадает.

Comment: Последний аргумент `print` должен быть `substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH+1)`, наверное.

Comment: @mkkik у меня не пропадает,  странно

Comment: Проверил [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php). И правда, не пропадает. Почему у меня пропадает, не понимаю.